# Detecting jquery ajax method being called using ajaxSend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajaxSend to hook on to ajax requests in jQuery. What I want to be able to do is determine whether the load method is used. So when this call is made ...

```
$('.some-selector').load(url, {...});
```

I can handle it differently than a regular '$.ajax', '$.get', or '$.post' call. 
Is there a way to figure this out using the passed event, xhr, or options in the ajaxSend call?

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, xhr, options) {
    //Do something here to figure out if 'load' method was used 
    //And also determine what element(s) it was called against
});
```

Comment: I would be surprised if there is any way to tell since `.load` is simply a call to `.ajax` internally.  A quick glance at the source of `load` didn't turn up any identifying info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override `load`.

```
jQuery.fn.load = (function (jqLoadFn) {
    return function () {
        console.log('intercepted');

        return jqLoadFn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(jQuery.fn.load);
```

Comment: I was thinking of this as an option but wasn't sure if there was a different solution. Thanks for your input I'll see how it goes

Comment: @giovanMusk I dont think that there are any other ways.